# sharepoint csom get address and phonenumber from current user

Tags: 2013, client-object-model

I am building some CSOM code in my DispForm.aspx. I try to get the current user from the context. This works and I can get the loginName, id, title and email. But I would like to have the address and phonenumber of the current user. Is this possible client side?

**THIS CODE IS WORKING**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js');
var currentUser;
function init(){
    this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
    currentUser = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
    this.clientContext.load(currentUser);
    this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    document.getElementById('userLoginName').innerHTML = currentUser.get_loginName(); 
    document.getElementById('userId').innerHTML = currentUser.get_id();
    document.getElementById('userTitle').innerHTML = currentUser.get_title();
    document.getElementById('userEmail').innerHTML = currentUser.get_email();
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
<div>Current Logged User:
    <span id="userLoginName"></span>
    <span id="userId"></span>
    <span id="userTitle"></span>
    <span id="userEmail"></span>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use [SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager.getMyProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj679865(v=office.15).aspx) to load user properties for the current user in JSOM, for example:

```
function getMyProperties(success,error)
{
      var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
      var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(context);
      var myProperties = peopleManager.getMyProperties();

      context.load(myProperties);
      context.executeQueryAsync(
      function () {
         success(myProperties);
      }, 
      error
   ); 
}
```

Usage

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {
   SP.SOD.executeFunc('userprofile', 'SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager', function() {

   getMyProperties(
       function(myProperties){
          var workPhone = myProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['WorkPhone'];
          var office = myProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['Office'];
       },
       function(sender,args){
           console.log(args.get_message());
       }
   );

   });

});
```

> [SP.SOD.executeFunc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409592(v=office.14).aspx) is used to ensure UserProfile JS Library
>   (`SP.UserProfiles.js`) is loaded in SharePoint 2013

Comment: nice man, works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Use following code and and then look at this: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj679700(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj679700%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to access the collection of properties returned.

Include following js

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" name="SP.js" runat="server"
    ondemand="false" localizable="false" loadafterui="true" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink2" name="SP.UserProfiles.js" runat="server"
    ondemand="false" localizable="false" loadafterui="true" />


var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);
    var personProperties = peopleManager.getMyProperties();
    clientContext.load(currentUser);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail);
```

Comment: Thanks Ashish, I get only this error with your example code: Error: Unable to get property 'PeopleManager' of undefined or null reference. How does it come?

Comment: Please see my comments about including the appropriate JS Library. Looks like you are missing SP.UserProfile.js